# What is the difference between np.cov(array) and array.cov()?

Tags: programming, covariance, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to find a covariance matrix, so when i use `returns.cov()` on my returns variable, I get a good result. Unfortunately, when i want to use `.cov()` on my np array converted from pandas df, i must use np.cov(array). But then, i get a completely different matrix, that is not even the dimensions that it should be. How to get a normal covariance matrix while using np.cov(array) or how to convert this crazy matrix into a normal one?
Here is my code:

```
returns = np.log(data).diff()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
cov_matrix
```

Output:

```
            GE      MSFT       JNJ         K        BA       IBM
GE    0.103503  0.075849  0.022159 -0.004298  0.085745  0.012300
MSFT  0.075849  0.165744  0.041228 -0.005173  0.037925 -0.002240
JNJ   0.022159  0.041228  0.035968  0.018111  0.010101 -0.003933
K    -0.004298 -0.005173  0.018111  0.056953 -0.007621 -0.004619
BA    0.085745  0.037925  0.010101 -0.007621  0.089571  0.024823
IBM   0.012300 -0.002240 -0.003933 -0.004619  0.024823  0.018391
```

here is the other code using np.cov(array):

```
cov_matrix = np.cov(returns)
cov_matrix
```

output:

```
array([[        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan],
       [        nan,  0.08709179, -0.02110741,  0.02440574,  0.028228  ,
         0.01615291, -0.00658686,  0.07601494,  0.03515373, -0.04674915,
        -0.03947769,  0.03605138],
       [        nan, -0.02110741,  0.02745833,  0.00419789,  0.00786532,
         0.00018428,  0.03678159, -0.00574526, -0.02711512,  0.01241536,
        -0.00982581, -0.01954344],
       [        nan,  0.02440574,  0.00419789,  0.02056029,  0.0081328 ,
         0.01348074,  0.0125812 ,  0.02001429,  0.00479978, -0.01069634,
        -0.02331694,  0.00175948],
       [        nan,  0.028228  ,  0.00786532,  0.0081328 ,  0.08130515,
         0.01101311,  0.07589644,  0.06730002, -0.04176551, -0.02758789,
        -0.04104097,  0.01693321],
       [        nan,  0.01615291,  0.00018428,  0.01348074,  0.01101311,
         0.02619104,  0.0244941 ,  0.0028883 , -0.01552481, -0.01530776,
        -0.0314189 ,  0.00692483],
       [        nan, -0.00658686,  0.03678159,  0.0125812 ,  0.07589644,
         0.0244941 ,  0.11670208,  0.03269149, -0.08127712, -0.01149054,
        -0.05617884, -0.00707836],
       [        nan,  0.07601494, -0.00574526,  0.02001429,  0.06730002,
         0.0028883 ,  0.03269149,  0.10320532,  0.01023065, -0.04249818,
        -0.04005964,  0.03031267],
       [        nan,  0.03515373, -0.02711512,  0.00479978, -0.04176551,
        -0.01552481, -0.08127712,  0.01023065,  0.0724934 , -0.0045111 ,
         0.02626014,  0.01213532],
       [        nan, -0.04674915,  0.01241536, -0.01069634, -0.02758789,
        -0.01530776, -0.01149054, -0.04249818, -0.0045111 ,  0.03077156,
         0.02965359, -0.02410751],
       [        nan, -0.03947769, -0.00982581, -0.02331694, -0.04104097,
        -0.0314189 , -0.05617884, -0.04005964,  0.02626014,  0.02965359,
         0.05648698, -0.01213576],
       [        nan,  0.03605138, -0.01954344,  0.00175948,  0.01693321,
         0.00692483, -0.00707836,  0.03031267,  0.01213532, -0.02410751,
        -0.01213576,  0.02393791]])
```

Comment: I'm not an everyday Python user. However, in terms of *np.cov(returns)*, have you tried transposing your returns and observing whether it equates to the same covariance matrix when using pandas dataframe, ie. *np.cov(returns.transpose())*? Two other things: Remove the first row of your returns that is equal to "nan" (removes nan values of numpy covariance estimate) and moreover, when using numpy's covariance function, set "ddof=1" to get the unbiased covariance estimate. See documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html). Does this make a difference?

Comment: Man you are the boss!!! Tranposing the matrix solved the problem, I really don't know why that was sabotaging the whole function. I left nan values because I could not remove them using numpy. I needed to convert to pandas, use pandas.dropna, and then convert back to numpy. The reason is because returns = returns[~np.isnan(returns)] didn't work. Thanks one more time for helping me, and btw, do you know why I needed to transpose the matrix in this second situation?